# Bootstrap - Input group doesn't work

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to align inputs and buttons using the .input-group class as shown [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons).

It works well and shows the desired output when I place a button before the text box.

But, when I place the button next to the text box, the button doesn't stay close to the text box.

I am using Bootstrap 3 in my ASP.NET project, created using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: That is not my experience, per [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/anLbo1o1/).  Can you share more - browser? Version? ACTUAL rendered markup, vs "coded" markup?

Comment: Can you post your rendered output, if you're using MVC or webforms?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem and I looked at cale_b's fiddle and it appeared correct for me.  So I scratched my head trying to figure out what was different in my environment. I noticed that in my site.css (my custom css for my app), I had the following:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Once I removed (or commented out) that CSS, then it worked.  But now I need to find a different approach to default the max-widths on my inputs.  Oh well, at least it solved my problem, hope it solved yours.

Comment: Worked for me too. Asp .Net MVC adds a default Site.css in Content folder with theese css markup.

Comment: Always so easy to forget that even your empty MVC template's styles can be overriding your bootstrap css